# "Make run" print "bin/prog" in terminal

Tags: c++, makefile

When I run "make run" in the terminal, the program print bin/prog, but I don't want this. Please look the Makefile:

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -W -Wall -ansi -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -pedantic
SRCFILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
run: bin/prog
    bin/prog
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question should have the `c++11` tag.

Comment: Sorry, i used this tag because i'm using make in a c++11 program

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to use `@` to silence this output.  See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html).

You might also be interested in reasons to *not* do that, and alternatives that are better; see http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: So, i just need to put the @ in the makefile ?

Comment: See the examples in the documentation.  If following them doesn't work, update your question with what you tried and the command you ran and the output you got, and explain in what way that's not what you wanted.

Comment: I saw the documentation, but when i put $(V).SILENT: in the final of the file, all of the  commands become invisible, but i just want to turn invisible the bin/prog when i do make run

Comment: If you just want to keep one line from being printed use `@`.  Given your desires you should not use the form in the blog post and stick to the manual (first link).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it !!